# How to configure PHP engine with Apache 2.2.x?

Tags: php, apache

i have installed Apache 2.2.x but when i turned to instal PHP V5.2.17 i didn't find the apache 2.2.x radio button in the web server setup step !! only the fast CGI,other CGI and don't install a web server radio buttons is appearing, what i can do ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you're talking about windows. Lining up a proper build of apache, php module, etc is a bit of a pain, so unless it's for production, I suggest using [WampServer](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) or [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html).

Otherwise, the PHP modules are [here](http://windows.php.net/download/) if you really want to roll your own. Remember to match the PHP and Apache runtimes and word-size (32 or 64 bit).

Comment: of course PHP and Apache instalers have the same word-size(by the by i use xp 32) but the problem remains, i can't find the reason!

Comment: php-5.2.17-nts-Win32-VC6-x86.msi ----                           apache_2.2.4-win32-x86-openssl-0.9.8d.msi

Comment: Eslam: Check out WampServer, it's really the best way to do Apache/PHP/MySQL on Windows. Keep in mind that all of that software was designed for Unix-clones, not Windows, so it can be a major hazzle to install them independently. WampServer works straight out of the box, and all the configuration is available in a cute little tray icon.

Comment: but WampServer has a downside in security,so it isn't appropriate for production use!